# AngularJS repeating data in a list

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

There is probably an easy solution for this:

I have some data in a controller, depending if item is selected it should display some html and if it's not selected it should display some other html.

If item is selected html should be:

```
<li>
    <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Selected:</span>Worldwide</a>
</li>
```

If item is not selected html should be:

```
<li>
    <a href="/example/link">Link</a>
</li>
```

This would be easily solved if I only had to change the class attribute, then I could something like `<span ng-class="dropdownItemClass(dropdownItem)">`

But I also need to add `aria-hidden="true"` if it's selected and remove it if it's not selected.

Comment: Add an example and i'll give you an answer based on your data.

Comment: You can use ng-if https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Comment: Will you please some more lines from your code ? So we can understand your question clearly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li ng-repeat="number in numbers">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="IsSelected">
    <a href="#" ng-if="!IsSelected"><span class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Selected:</span>Worldwide {{number}}
    </a>
    <a ng-if="IsSelected" href="/example/link">Link</a>
</li>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('example', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="example">

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="number in numbers">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="IsSelected">
        <a href="#" ng-if="!IsSelected"><span class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Selected:</span>Worldwide {{number}}
        </a>
        <a ng-if="IsSelected" href="/example/link">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```